# Pan the map depending on the zoom (how to do the math)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, math

http://jsfiddle.net/bor9zuhr/2/

On this Fiddle is an illustration of my problem. I have the navigation over the top of the map element. Now, when you click a marker, the map is being panned to the marker's coordinates, and the top of the info window most probably will not be readable when it is large enough.

What I want is to pan the map to a position above the marker, so that the info window falls lower, and will not be obscured by the navigation. Ideally, it would fall right in the middle of the visible area.

The problem is that when the map is zoomed in far, I need to pan it for a much smaller amount than if it were zoomed out far. And I can't seem to get the math right.

This is the part of the code that deals with the panning:

```
infowindow.open(map, marker);
var K = 0; // this should be something depending on the zoom level 
var lat = marker.getPosition().lat() + K;
var lng = marker.getPosition().lng();
var newCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
map.panTo(newCenter);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could call `map.panBy` at the end of your function.

From the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map):

> Changes the center of the map by the given distance in pixels. If the distance is less than both the width and height of the map, the transition will be smoothly animated. Note that the map coordinate system increases from west to east (for x values) and north to south (for y values).

With panBy you don't have to think about zoom levels, you just pan by pixels.